# How to interrupt Android boot sequence to force it boot to Linux kernel only

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to do some low level performance testing related to device processor cores through adb which I feel it is affected by Android background services and system stuff.

As I know that the Android boot sequence stages are as follow:

1. Execute Boot ROM code.
2. Execute the boot loader.
3. Load the Linux kernel.
4. Launch Zygote, which initializes the Dalvik VM.
5. System server which loads the Android system.

So my question is how can I interrupt this sequence to force it stop on stage 3 to load Linux kernel. This can help me implement my intermediary performance testings before loading again Android system.
Does Fastboot or Clockworkmod recovery can help here and load my device to a kind of Linux kernel?

Any hint will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Look in /init.rc and similar files.  Unfortunately these are no longer even *readable* on a secured consumer device - obviously you'd need an engineering device / custom rom install to be able to change them, but discouraging looking around is quite sad, and pretty pointless from a security perspective since the contents are available elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Change `init` parameter in kernel bootargs to something like `init=/bin/sh`. Usually it can be done somewhere on step 2.

Comment: This would not result in adbd running, which is necessary for the proposed means of testing, and unless the device has a console UART, it will be inaccessible.  What should be done is to modify the configuration of the init system so that it doesn't start the android runtime.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Yes that is right. But I wonder if there a way to modify the booting steps of init system so that it will prevent Android from booting? Any specific file responsible for that?